# Ошибка при компиляции..SDK

Tags: android

error: cannot find symbol class ResizableImageView

```
 mItemImg = (ResizableImageView) mListViewHeader.findViewById(R.id.itemImg);
```

Как исправить?

Comment: А есть у вас itemImg?

Comment: Видимо у вас библиотека нужна не подключена. Или подключена, но класс не импортирован